# Powershell & XML: Save data to a certain node of xml-file

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a powershell script which loads data from an xml. The XML looks like:

```
<meta>
<log>
    <path>D:\logs\l1.log</path>
    <lastwrite>01/30/2015 13:01:00</lastwrite>
    <num>23</num>
</log>
<log>
    <path>D:\log\l2.log</path>
    <lastwrite>02/30/2015 14:02:00</lastwrite>
    <num>67</num>
</log>
</meta>
```

What I would like to do is to change a certain value in the xml. First I load the Data:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content "D:\config.xml"
```

My problem is, how can I address a certain log-Node in my xml? What I'm searching for is something like this:

```
$xml.meta.log.path | where path = "D:\log\l2.log"
```

And also something to set the new value and save it back to the xml-file.

Maybe sb can help me, I have now idea how to search, but I'm sure there's a way. To use IDs within the log-tags is not a good solution, because I have to address the nodes by the paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I made a little change:
XML is now:

```
<meta>
<log path="D:\logs\l1.log">
    <lastwrite>01/30/2015 13:01:00</lastwrite>
    <num>23</num>
</log>
<log path="D:\log\l2.log">
    <lastwrite>02/30/2015 14:02:00</lastwrite>
    <num>67</num>
</log>
</meta>
```

And now this code works:

```
$configPath = 'D:\config.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $configPath

# Select the log log node where path equals 'D:\log\l2.log' 
$node = $xml.meta.log | where {$_.path -eq 'D:\log\l2.log'}

# Set the new path
$node.line_num = "5"

# Save the xml back
$xml.Save($configPath)
```

Path is not needed to be modified.

Thanks for your help. Wouldn't have been able to solve this without your code snippet;)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Instead of a `=` use the `-eq` condition. You also have to use curly brackets and access the current value using `$_`:

```
$xml.meta.log.Path | where { $_ -eq 'D:\log\l2.log' }
```

Alternative, you can use the `where path` query on `$xml.meta.log` and select the path in an additional statement:

```
$xml.meta.log | where path -eq 'D:\log\l2.log' | select -expand path
```

And here a complete example which modifies the path and save the xml back:

```
$configPath = 'D:\config.xml'

[xml]$xml = Get-Content $configPath

# Select the log log node where path equals 'D:\log\l2.log' 
$node = $xml.meta.log | where path -eq 'D:\log\l2.log' 

# Set the new path
$node.path = 'D:\newLogPath\newLog.log'

# Save the xml back
$xml.Save($configPath)
```

Comment: Looks good..but doesn't still work. I get an error message about the line where I set the new path. Error is sth like "The path property was not found within this object. Make sure it is available and determined"
Besides, when I want to print the node with "$node.meta.log.path" - nothing appears.

Comment: hm, the script works fine on my computer. What does $node contain if you print it out?